# Link posted to Facebook not redirecting to my native iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, redirect

When this link (http://bit.ly/1C3e7e7) is clicked within the Facebook app, I am promoted with a warning that I'm about to open another app, but then nothing happens.

Does Facebook not allow redirects to other apps even though they have the alert warning users that the redirect is about to take place?

Comment: Looks like someone already reported a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/431959116987296/